# Apply Authorization with a policy to all controllers within a namespace in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-authorization

Using ASP.NET 5 I've implemented an [Authorization Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0) that I'd like to apply to all controllers within a namespace, but NOT to all controllers in the project. Is there a way to do this other than add the attribute `[Authorize(Policy="MyPolicy")]` to each controller individually? I'd like to avoid the risk that another dev adds a new controller to the namespace but forgets to apply the policy.

It looks like this when doing it manually:

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize(Policy="MyPolicy")]
[Route("api/DoStuff")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{ 

    [HttpGet("foo")]
    public GetFoo() 
    {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just create a controller to inherit from and then apply it to whatever controllers you want? Something like

```
[Authorize(Policy="MyPolicy")]
public class BaseProtectedController : ControllerBase
{

}
```

And then inherit from this controller whenever you need `Authorize`

```
public class SomeProtectedController : BaseProtectedController
{

}
```

Comment: This isn't really what I wanted, but thanks for the suggestion it's definitely an option that'd be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 6):

You could implement the IControllerModelConvention and manage the policies according to the namespace of the controller from there

AddAuthorizeFiltersControllerConvention.cs

```cs
public class AddAuthorizeFiltersControllerConvention : IControllerModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
    {
        if (controller.ControllerType.Namespace == "My.Admin.Namespace")
        {
            controller.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("AdminPolicy"));
        }
        else 
        {
            controller.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("DefaultPolicy"));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can apply this controller model convention to your controllers in the ConfigureServices

Startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... Cutting everything else in the ConfigureServices for simplicity

    services.AddControllers(options => {
        options.Conventions.Add(new AddAuthorizeFiltersControllerConvention());
    });
}
```

Another example of this can be found here http://hpblogs.com/blogs/add-authorize-policy-dynamically-to-all-controllers-in-asp-net-core-3-1/48

Comment: Thank you!  This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to do this other than add the attribute `[Authorize(Policy="MyPolicy")]` to each controller individually? I'd like to avoid the risk that another dev adds a new controller to the namespace but forgets to apply the policy.

You can try to add an authorization filter and specify PolicyName, like below.

```
services.AddControllers(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("MyPolicy"));
});
```

Comment: Any idea how I can do this just for Controllers within one namespace and not others?